# ImageMagick - Trim / Crop to contiguous objects

Tags: imagemagick

How do you do the equivalent of this step in Photoshop.

https://gyazo.com/180a507c0f3c9b342fe33ce218cd512e

Supposed there are two contiguous objects in an image, and you want to create exact sized crops around each one and output as two files. (Generalize to N files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with *"Connected Component Analysis"* to find the contiguous blobs.

**Start Image**

[image]

```
convert shapes.png -colorspace gray -negate -threshold 10%  \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true                \
   -connected-components 8 -normalize output.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 416x310+0+0 212.3,145.2 76702 srgb(0,0,0)
  1: 141x215+20+31 90.0,146.2 26129 srgb(255,255,255)
  2: 141x215+241+75 311.0,190.2 26129 srgb(255,255,255)
```

Notice how each blob, or contiguous object, is *"labelled"* or identified with its own unique colour (shade of grey).

[image]

So there is a header line telling you what the fields are followed by 3 blobs, i.e. one per line of output. The first line is the entire image and not much use. The second one is 141 px wide and 215 px tall starting at +20+31 from the top-left corner. The third one is the same size (because I copied the shape) and starts as +241+75 from the top-left corner.

Now stroke red around the final indicated rectangle - bearing in mind that `rectangle` takes top-left and bottom-right corners rather than top-left corner plus width and height.

```
convert shapes.png -stroke red -fill none -draw "rectangle 241,75 382,290" z.png
```

And crop it:

```
convert shapes.png -crop 141x215+241+75 z.png
```

[image]

And here is the extracted part:

[image]

---

If you want to generalise, you can just pipe the **ImageMagick** output into `awk` and pick out the geometry field:

```
convert shapes.png -colorspace gray -negate -threshold 10%  -define connected-components:verbose=true  -connected-components 8 -normalize output.png | awk 'NR>2{print $2}'
```

**Sample Output**

```
141x215+20+31
141x215+241+75
```

Comment: do you have suggestions on optimizations for shapes that are a little bit less solid/rigid/bright distinct colors? i.e. typical product photos

Comment: It depends on the photos. Basically you need to do something that makes the thing you want white, and the thing you don't want black. I'd have to see the photos - maybe you need Otsu thresholding, maybe you need blurring and thresholding, maybe you need to threshold the saturation. I can't say till I see representative images - an answer is only as good as the question and the information it supplies.

Comment: this also seems to represent a hard case to try to blob using this method.

Comment: It seems the images in your question were maybe not the most representative of your actual images. Consider asking a new question (they are free, after all) with better images, and maybe consider being open to solutions based on Python/scikit/OpenCV as well as ImageMagick to attract a better variety of solutions.

Comment: Actually! Wrong link - sorry! I meant https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/614RpehON0L._UL1500_.jpg

Comment: Okay asked a new question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100307/imagemagick-general-way-to-convert-background-removed-product-photo-into-masked